# Parse.com Stripe: Creating a charge that is not captured

Tags: parse-platform, httprequest, stripe-payments

I'm working on an iOS app that uses Stripe to process payments. We are moving from a system that uses two separate charges for initial purchase and tip to a system that uses a single charge that begins as a hold on the user's account and then is captured upon setting the tip. This was the system that Stripe recommended to us when we inquired how to work with a single charge but also validate that the card can handle a charge of the designated amount.

For our back end, we are using Parse.com to track our orders, and so we are using Stripe's integration with Parse.com's Cloud Code as our server. Our main issue is that Parse.com doesn't seem to outright support most of Stripe's functionality (i.e. capturing charges). After some searching, I found that http POST requests were the best option to interact with Stripe.js and actually capture charges. However, I haven't been able to get quite that far because Parse.com is giving me a Code 141 error (*Received unknown parameter: captured*) when I try to create a charge that is uncaptured. Parse.com's Stripe API suggests that you can set all parameters through their Stripe.Charges.create, but it won't accept *captured* as a valid parameter.

> To abstract for anyone else with this issue, how can I create a charge that has the parameter **captured** set to false using **Parse.com** Stripe API?

I have posted some of my Cloud Code below that should define a method to create a charge that has not yet been captured. This method is what is giving me the error that captured is not a valid parameter.

```
/**
 * Create Hold on Card
 * Required:
 * orderCostInCents                      -- in cents  ex. $10.24 = 1024
 * customer                              -- cus_11EXEXEXEXEXEX
 * description                           -- order.objectId to link it with order item.
 */
 Parse.Cloud.define("holdAccount", function(request, response) {
               //response.success("Not Charged");
               var Stripe = require("stripe");
               Stripe.initialize(kStripePrivateKey);
               Stripe.Charges.create({
                                     amount : request.params.orderCostInCents,
                                     currency : "usd",
                                     customer : request.params.customer,
                 captured : false,
                                     description : request.params.description
                                     },{
                                     success: function(httpResponse) {
                                     console.log(httpResponse);
                                     response.success(httpResponse);
                                     },
                                     error: function(httpResponse) {
                                     console.log(httpResponse.message);
                                     response.error("Failed to create charge");
                                     }
                                     });
               });
```

I believe that I can structure an http (POST) request after creating the charge by following the guidelines set at https://www.parse.com/questions/stripe-payment-capture-method-not-available. This guide might be very helpful to anyone else with my issue!

Best, and thanks for your help!

> **Edit:** I realized that I didn't post the version of Cloud Code that we are using. It is 1.2.19.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, after taking a break from my hours of staring at the screen, I certainly feel like a doofus! The parameter I was using was captured, where the correct parameter should be **capture**. I was able to fix my issue by simply removing the "d" from the parameter name while creating the charge.

Whoops! I would still be open to advice on http requests via comments, but I will test those on my own and post a separate thread if I run into issues there as that issue is tangential to this one and thus off-topic.

> For everyone joining, the answer is that the above code works perfectly if you replace the parameter **captured** with **capture**

**Edit**: For anyone else that is interested, the follow-up to this question was about actually making the capture via http requests on Parse Cloud Code. The following method works after much searching and trial and error. The hardest part here was figuring out how to format the URL since this is my first foray into http requests. If you need to chain parameters, simply add "&{parameter-name}={parameter-value}"

```
//kStripePrivateKey is your stripe private key
//Must pass in chargeID = stripe charge id and 
    //orderCostInCents = capture amount in cents as parameters
var captureURL  = "https://"+ kStripePrivateKey +
            ":@api.stripe.com/v1/charges/"+
            request.params.chargeID+
            "/capture?amount="+request.params.orderCostInCents;

Parse.Cloud.httpRequest({
    url: captureURL,
    method: 'POST',
    success: function(httpResponse) {
        // Handle any success actions here
        response.success(httpResponse);
    }, error: function(httpResponse) {
        response.error(httpResponse);
    }
});
```